# Can a Mobx State Tree cause "race conditions" / works only with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, mobx

Using **mobx-state-tree**. I have a `ListStore` which contains this action:

```
 remove: process(function* remove(id) {
    try {
      self.markBeingRemoved(id); // set flag in store
      const element = yield getEnv(self).resource.remove(id); // async call
      self.removeFromList(element.id); // see below
      showSuccessNotification(); // some jQuery based notification library
    } catch (err) {
      showServerError();
    } finally {
      self.markBeingRemoved(null);
    }
  })
```

Now ***`removeFromList`*** simply does:

```
 const indexToRemove = self.list.findIndex(e => e.id === elementId);
    if (indexToRemove >= 0) {
      self.list.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
```

Now i have a React component that uses the list. It is injected like `@inject('ListStore')`. Then i pass it to subcomponents as props. The sub-components that use it, are all mobx-`observer`s.

I get this obscure error, which Google does know nothing about:

```
mobx-state-tree.module.js?9486:50 Uncaught Error: [mobx-state-tree] 
This object has died and is no longer part of a state tree. 
It cannot be used anymore. 
The object (of type 'Template') used to live at '/list/1'. It is 
possible to access the last snapshot of this object using 
'getSnapshot', or to create a fresh copy using 'clone'. If you want to 
remove an object from the tree without killing it, use 'detach' 
instead.

at fail (webpack-internal:///467:92:11)
at Object.get (webpack-internal:///467:1409:17)
at Object.get [as id] (webpack-internal:///33:1682:28)
at dehydrate
at dehydrate (chrome-
extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8154:24)
at dehydrate (chrome-
extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8154:24)
at chrome-
extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:7285:20
at Array.map (native)
at Bridge.flushBufferSlice (chrome-
extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:7280:33)
at Bridge.flushBufferWhileIdle (chrome-
extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:7268:15)
fail @ mobx-state-tree.module.js?9486:50
get @ mobx-state-tree.module.js?9486:1367
get @ mobx.module.js?cbdf:1638
dehydrate @ backend.js:8154
dehydrate @ backend.js:8154
dehydrate @ backend.js:8154
    (anonymous) @ backend.js:72
flushBufferSlice @ backend.js:7280
flushBufferWhileIdle @ backend.js:726
```

Now comes the interesting part: If i put the call of ***`removeFromList`*** into a `setTimeout(..., 1000)`, **it works!**

Why?

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(element.id);` right before `self.removeFromList(element.id);`?

Comment: The correct element id. I should have mentioned that everything works as expected, the element **is** removed, but still this error is shown in theconsole.

Comment: The funny (or strange?) thing is that `setTimeout(() => self.removeFromList...,  1000)` makes it work...

Comment: Very interesting. Sounds like something worth creating an issue over. Do you think you can create a small isolated example?

Comment: I have created an issue here: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/416. Yes i will make a repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is triggered by the react developer tools.

They are holding in memory an object that died, and that's why they are throwing. In production without devtools they won't trigger that error.

Comment: I should have googled for "fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi" :-)